# Unable to get refresh tokens in OAuth 2.0 Jira Service Desk integration

Tags: oauth-2.0, jira, jira-rest-api

I have enabled OAuth 2.0 and used the access token to call Jira Service Desk Rest endpoints.

**Problem:** access token expires every 1 hour.
According to the documentation OAuth 2.0 there are 2 ways to get new access token when it expires

- Initiate the entire authorization flow from the beginning again.
- Use a refresh token to get another access token.

Step 1 does not make any sense as it redirects to webpage and manual intervention is required to authorise the app. 
To use Step 2 I dont get refresh token at all https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general a short term access token is given. In order to get a long term refresh token offline_access scope should be specified in the the authorization URL to get an authorization code.

```
https://auth.atlassian.com/authorize?
  audience=api.atlassian.com&
  client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
  scope=REQUESTED_SCOPE_ONE%20REQUESTED_SCOPE_TWO&
  redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP_CALLBACK_URL&
  state=YOUR_USER_BOUND_VALUE&
  response_type=code&
  prompt=consent
```

Here in scope it should be `scope=REQUESTED_SCOPE_ONE%20REQUESTED_SCOPE_TWO%20offline_access&`